# Dynamic number of thumbs according to available area in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, thumbnails

I'm creating a photo gallery website, and there are pages for browsing the photos, with a listing of thumbnails (yes just a regular photo site). The problem is that, I want thumbnails to fill up the available space (I know how to get that one). Actually, what I want to achieve is very similar to this: imagine you have a big number of (more than the screen area allows) thumbnails, and you have set overflow-y to hidden. The thumbs just fill up the space and it goes, off the screen. This would be what I wanted to have if the thumbs in the bottom didn't go off the screen. I need something more, let's say, "dynamic". I've got jQuery, but haven't been able to model the desired effect in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the way into it anyway. I just load a big number of thumbs, set the overflow-y of the thumbs container to hidden, and by Javascript (actually jQuery), when I resize the window check if the thumbs top + height exceeds window's height. if it does, I simply hide that thumb, if it doesn't I simply show it. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

You should load the images dynamically as needed to improve performance. See the "Reduce the Number of DOM Elements" section in the [Yahoo! Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). Use jQuery to check the size of the div in which you are rendering the images. Load just enough images to fill the div and then load more images on the fly as needed (on window resize or scroll). It is not clear to me exactly what you want to achieve so I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: I will load more when user clicks something like "load more", but just initially, on page load, I want to load, a "high enough" number of thumbs, for almost any screen size (e.g. enough to fill 2560x1600 etc) and display the ones that fit in, so if user resizes the window to something bigger, thumb will show up (not an ajax load, it will already be there but hidden and will just become visible). So this is more of a CSS or javascript issue than loading on the fly. I'm lust talking about that initial load where user hasn't clicked "load more" or scrolled. I just need to handle resizes w/o ajax.